# How to wait until .done() is done before proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute `$(".foo").fadeIn("slow");` after everything from `.done()` is done.

Right now whenever the fadeIn is called I can still see how the text is being changed live because jQuery doesn't wait until it's done with that.

How would I go about doing that?

```
$(".notice").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://graph.facebook.com/name",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $(".foo .bar").text(data.name);
    });
    $(".foo").fadeIn("slow"); //
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't put it in the `.done()` aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code inside the callback of the `jQuery.done` method

```
$(".notice").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://graph.facebook.com/name",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $(".foo .bar").text(data.name);

        $(".foo").fadeIn("slow"); //
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Move it into your ajax-done function:

```
$(".notice").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://graph.facebook.com/name",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $(".foo .bar").text(data.name);
        $(".foo").fadeIn("slow"); //move it here and it will be called if your ajax request is ready
        callMethod(); //alternative you can call a mehtod
    });
});

function callMethod() {
    $(".foo").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [chain of done](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://graph.facebook.com/name",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON"
}).done(function(data) {
    $(".foo .bar").text(data.name);
}).done(function() {
   $(".foo").fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2c7Fy/)

Comment: it is exactly what he asked: fadeIn after ALL instructions in first done().

Comment: I agree that's what he want, but that is overkill. Except if there's something he didn't show us, `.done()` are used for deffered object or queue. That is not the case here. Chained done are used for chained async calls. Performance wise the accepted answer is the best, but of course, in other context, your would be better.